# Python DTW Package Correlation and Cosine Distance not Working

Tags: python, dtw

I am trying to use the dtw function like:

```
alignment = dtw(x, y, dist_method='correlation')
```

However, the 'cosine' and 'correlation' never worked regardless of my input data (other measures such as euclidean always work). The error message is:

```
ValueError: No warping path found compatible with the local constraints
```

So I tried all different combinations of other parameters:
open_begin/open_end: True of False
step_pattern: 'symmetric2' or 'asymmetric'

I still get the same error.

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Topic may be interesting but You need to provide some code to reproduce problem.

Comment: Below is an example, but really regardless my x and y values, the same error i get.x = [23.0, -24.0, 8.0, 12.0, 22.0, -1.0, -24.0, .0, -24.0, 12.0, 2.0, 0.0, -24.0, 0.0, 24.0, 25.0, -24.0, -68.0, -71.0]
y = [20.0, -20.0, 6.0, 6.0, 10.0, 0.0, -10.0, 2.0, -10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 1.0, -12.0, 2.0, 13, -30]
alignment = dtw(x, y, dist_method='cosine')
print(alignment.distance)